# Start new activity with start values

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I know that we can start new activity with the steps as follows :

1. Design new XML file that contains layout details ( LinearLayout,
   RelativeLayout, etc ) and add user defined widgets ( Button, TextView, ... )
2. Add activiy name and label details to AndroidManifest.xml like below

   ```
   <activity android:name=".NewActivity" android:label="@string/new_activity_header" />
   ```
3. Define new Intent and call startActivity to start new activity.

But, i want to start new activity with start argument that will be changed in different calls.

For example :

- Main activity XML layout file:

  ```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/button" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```

I want to do this :
If we press **Button**, new activity will be started and show the random number that generated in main activity.

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(10000);

        //Some code will be placed here !
    }
});
```

But how can i initialize new activity class field members?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        int rand = new Random().nextInt(10000);
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClass.class);       
        i.putExtra("random", rand);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

and in your activity:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b = getIntent().getExtras();
int value = b.getInt("random");
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) As i see, all answers are true, but you do it immediately, and i accept your answer too :)

Answer (score 1):

Add like this to your activity

```
 <application
      android:name="com.uncocoder.test.activity.G"
      ....>
 </application>
```

then create class G like this

```
public class G extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        //do your works here
    }
}
```

So before activating any activity your code will run.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add the random number to the intent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, <Your Activity>.class);
intent.putExtra("rand", rand);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in the onCreate of your new activity get the value with:

```
rand = getIntent().getIntExtra("rand", 0);
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

In your main activity, in the onClick method, create an Intent.  Then you can add data to the Intent by using intent.putExtra.  Then you can call startActivity and give it the Intent.

In your new Activity that you are starting you can call getIntent and extract the 'extras' that you put in it before.